# Reducing multiple chainable update_all calls into a single UPDATE statement

Tags: elixir, ecto

So let's say that I have a module for User and it has 2 functions that accept a changeset and add changes to it, like this ->

```
defmodule MyApp.User do

  def confirm(changeset_or_struct) do
    changeset_or_struct
    |> Ecto.Changeset.change(confirmed: true, confirmed_at: Timex.now())
  end

  def update_session(changeset_or_struct, ip_address) do
    changeset_or_struct
    |> Ecto.Changeset.change(session_token: "token", ip_address: ip_address)
  end
end
```

So if I need to apply both of those changes to a specific user and save them, I can easily chain those function calls like this

```
some_user
|> User.confirm()
|> User.update_session("ip_address")
|> Repo.update!()
```

So it's all good.

Now, let's say that for some reason I need to confirm and update session for a lot of users at the same time in an atomic manner. Obviously getting all those users, locking them and then updating one by one inside a transaction is not a really good option so we need to leverage the `update_all` function to send only one `UPDATE` statement.

So what we need is this ->

```
User
|> Repo.update_all([set: confirmed: true, confirmed_at: Timex.now(), session_token: "token", ip_address: "ip_address"])
```

But calling this code outside of the `User` module doesn't seem like a good idea because I want only the `User` module to know how to handle confirmation and sessions updates. So the next obvious decision is to create a function in the `User` module and put that code there but the problem with it is that it's not flexible because those two actions ( confirmation and session update ) are coupled together now. But we can just break it into 2 functions

```
def confirm_many(query) do
  query
  |> Repo.update_all([set: confirmed: true, confirmed_at: Timex.now()])
end


def update_session_many(query, ip_address) do
  query
  |> Repo.update_all([set: session_token: "token", ip_address: ip_address])
end
```

And even though now they are not coupled now but neither they are chainable so even though I can use those two separately, most likely I will end up with an ugly piece of code and a bunch of `UPDATE` statements when it could easily be reduced to only one. So now the question:

How would I do that? Is there a way to chain a bunch of independent updates which eventually could be reduced to a single `update_all` call?

So the bottom line is that I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
User
|> where([u], u.id in bunch_of_ids)
|> User.confirm_many()
|> User.update_session_many("ip_address")
|> Repo.update_all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ecto.Query.update` to incrementally build an update query, and only pass it to `Repo.update_all` at the end:

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  ...
  def confirm_many(query) do
    query
    |> update([set: [confirmed: true, confirmed_at: ^Ecto.DateTime.utc()]])
  end


  def update_session_many(query, ip_address) do
    query
    |> update([set: [session_token: "token", ip_address: ^ip_address]])
  end
end
```

With this, the following code:

```
import Ecto.Query
alias MyApp.{Repo, User}

User
|> where([u], u.id in [1, 2, 3])
|> User.confirm_many()
|> User.update_session_many("ip_address")
|> Repo.update_all([])
```

executes the query:

```
UPDATE "users" AS u0
  SET "confirmed" = TRUE,
      "confirmed_at" = $1,
      "session_token" = 'token',
      "ip_address" = $2
  WHERE (u0."id" IN (1,2,3))
[{{2017, 5, 21}, {11, 13, 43, 0}}, "ip_address"]
```